# lxml: some XML from URL give this lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I have a script which is suppose to extract some terms from XML files from a list of URLs.
All the URL's give access to XML data.

It is working fine at first opening, parsing and extracting correctly but then get interrupted in the process by some XML files with this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 18, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2953, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:56204)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1555, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82511)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1585, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82832)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1468, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:81688)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1024, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:78735)
  File "parser.pxi", line 569, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74472)
  File "parser.pxi", line 650, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:75363)
  File "parser.pxi", line 590, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:74696)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty, line 1, column 1
```

From my search it might be because some XML files have white spaces but i'm not sure if it is the problem. I can't tell which files give the error.
Is there a way to get around this error?

Here is my script:

```
URLlist = ["http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"+x+".xml" for x in IDlist]
for id, item in zip(IDlist, URLlist):
    goterm_location = []
    goterm_function = []
    goterm_process = []
    location_list[id] = []
    function_list[id] = []
    biological_list[id] = []
    try:
        textfile = urllib2.urlopen(item);
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        print("URL", item, "could not be read.")
        continue
    #Try to solve empty line error#
    tree = etree.parse(textfile);
    #root = tree.getroot()
    for node in tree.iter('{http://uniprot.org/uniprot}dbReference'):
        if node.attrib.get('type') == 'GO':
            for child in node:
                value = child.attrib.get('value');
                if value.startswith('C:'):
                    goterm_C = node.attrib.get('id')
                    if goterm_C:
                        location_list[id].append(goterm_C);
                if value.startswith('F:'):
                    goterm_F = node.attrib.get('id')
                    if goterm_F:
                        function_list[id].append(goterm_F);
                if value.startswith('P:'):
                    goterm_P = node.attrib.get('id')
                    if goterm_P:
                        biological_list[id].append(goterm_P);
```

I have tried:

```
tree = etree.iterparse(textfile, events = ("start","end"));
OR
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse(textfile, parser)
```

Without success.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The first step would be to figure out precisely which URL gives the error. Can you add `print` statements to determine which URL fails?

Comment: I did find the URL that give the error and in fact it is an empty XML
Is there a way to add an exception in my script to avoid empty XML and keep the process flowing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't tell which files give the error

Debug by printing the name of the file/URL prior to parsing. Then you'll see which file(s) cause the error.

Also, read the error message:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty, line 1, column 1
```

this suggests that the downloaded XML file is empty. Once you have determined the URL(s) that cause the problem, try downloading the file and check its contents. I suspect it might be empty.

You can ignore problematic files (empty or otherwise syntactically invalid) by using a try/except block when parsing:

```
try:
    tree = etree.parse(textfile)
except lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError:
    print 'Skipping invalid XML from URL {}'.format(item)
    continue    # go on to the next URL
```

Or you could check just for empty files by checking the 'Content-length' header, or even by reading the resource returned by `urlopen()`, but I think that the above is better as it will also catch other potential errors.

Comment: I checked the list of item and in fact the URL that break the process is linked to an empty XML. is there a way to add in the script an exception in order to bypass empty XML and avoid process interruption?

Comment: You could catch the `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError` exception by wrapping the parse operation in a `try/except` block. See update to answer.

Comment: Thanks it works now till the end.
I will try to see if there is problem of update for the URL that are not working.
Also I will try to see if there is a way to make a stream of the XML result in a tar.gz (so do all URL query to the server at once) instead of hammering the server with multiple request with the loop

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message in Python 3.6

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty, line 1, column 1
```

In my case the xml file is not empty. Issue is because of encoding,

Initially used **utf-8**,

```
from lxml import etree
etree.iterparse(my_xml_file.xml, tag='MyTag', encoding='utf-8')
```

changing encoding to **iso-8859-1** solved my issue,

```
etree.iterparse(my_xml_file.xml, tag='MyTag', encoding='iso-8859-1')
```