# Pandas read_html throws ParseError: Document is empty because of emoji

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

While scraping a web page searching for tables using `Pandas.read_html()`, I get into this error due to emojis in the html source:

```
lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty
```

I have tried both reading directly from the html source (as string) and reading the `<table>` tag extracted from the html.

For the scraping, I am using Selenium and Beautiful Soup including `html5lib` and `lxml` to allow Pandas to interpret html.

Since the page that I am scraping is very large, let me post a reproducible example.

Suppose that you have extracted the `<table>` tag from the html source with `soup.find_all("table")`, so that the string that you want to parse is `table_tag`:

```
import pandas as pd

table_tag = """<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Notfall Software </td>
    <td>Mario Müller</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Pélican</td>
    <td>Francisco Villa </td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>"""

tables = pd.read_html(table_tag, encoding='utf-8') # FAILS HERE
df = tables[0] # extract the 1-st as there is only one table
```

If you manually remove the emojis from the string, you get the correct result without errors:

```
>>> df
                    Company          Contact  Country
0          Notfall Software     Mario Müller  Germany
1  Centro comercial Pélican  Francisco Villa   Mexico
```

However, I cannot manually edit the original large html source, especially when I am scraping about 100 pages.

How do I read the source without errors or how do I remove the emojis as I won't need them anyway?

A snapshot of my requirements.txt (the essentials for this post):

```
pandas==2.0.2
selenium==4.12.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
webdriver-manager==3.8.6
lxml==4.9.2
html5lib==1.1
```

Comment: Using your example issue can't be reproduced https://monosnap.com/file/dLUKMjrUU1y3NgDwgdeLoyM6ConsDA

Maybe emoji is not the issue? Python 3.11.4, Pandas 2.0.3, lxml 4.9.3, MacOS Ventura 13.4

Comment: On my side, with or without does make a difference. Your versions are slightly more up to date: Python 3.11.3, lxml==4.9.2, pandas==2.0.2 also on MacOS.

Comment: I posted an proposal as an answer to remove them via regexp. If it doesn't help you - lmk, I'll remove answer. 

If it wouldn't help - probably, emojies is not an issue, if it would help - there is a bug in the one of that libs (lxml or pandas)

Comment: I wonder if [encoding is relevant as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66474505/1175496). But you use `utf-8`, and so do we (it still works; we can't reproduce the problem). Right now your question may be closed unless others can reproduce! Maybe you could reproduce this in some online Python runtime like Google Colab or something else? Or post the original code, even though it scrapes large webpages, maybe we can reproduce the problem from the original code...

Comment: The large web page is not reproducible as it has restricted access. The smaller example code that I have posted is sufficient to throw the same error on my machine. I would try with upgrading the libraries.

Comment: After testing with the updated libraries, the code still keeps on giving the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure that emojies is your issue, but you can remove it, using regexp with emojies unicode ranges.

Most common ranges

```
"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # Emoticons
"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # Symbols & Pictographs
"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # Transport & Map Symbols
"\U0001F700-\U0001F77F"  # Alchemical Symbols
"\U0001F780-\U0001F7FF"  # Geometric Shapes
"\U0001F800-\U0001F8FF"  # Supplemental Arrows-C
"\U0001F900-\U0001F9FF"  # Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
"\U0001FA00-\U0001FA6F"  # Chess Symbols
"\U0001FA70-\U0001FAFF"  # Symbols and Pictographs Extended-A
"\U0001F004-\U0001F0CF"  # Additional Emoticons
"\U0001F0D0-\U0001F0FF"  # Playing Cards
"\U0001F10D-\U0001F10F"  # Appliance
"\U0001F004-\U0001F251"  # Additional Emoticons
```

However, I can't reproduce your issue on lib versions Python==3.11.3, lxml==4.9.2, pandas==2.0.2

[Reference to a question where can be found all emoji ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470079/emoji-value-range)

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def remove_emojis(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                               "\U0001F600-\U0001F64F" 
                               "\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"
                               "\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  
                               "\U0001F700-\U0001F77F"
                               "\U0001F780-\U0001F7FF"
                               "\U0001F800-\U0001F8FF"
                               "\U0001F900-\U0001F9FF"
                               "\U0001FA00-\U0001FA6F"
                               "\U0001FA70-\U0001FAFF"
                               "\U0001F004-\U0001F0CF"
                               "\U0001F0D0-\U0001F0FF"
                               "\U0001F10D-\U0001F10F"
                               "\U0001F004-\U0001F251"
                               "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)

    return emoji_pattern.sub('', html)

table_tag = """<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Notfall Software </td>
    <td>Mario Müller</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Pélican</td>
    <td>Francisco Villa </td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>"""

tables = pd.read_html(remove_emojis(table_tag), encoding='utf-8')
df = tables[0]
print(df)
```

Comment: Indeed, it helps. I was working out something similar using regex substitution: `table_tag = re.sub(r"([\U0001F601-\U0001F64F]|[\U0001F680-\U0001F6C0])", '', table_tag)` using the ranges for the basic emojis and the transportations emojis (mostly occurring in my real use case). I found the unicodes at https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: I might also try updating the libraries, though, as you also say, it's pretty strange that this is the issue.

Comment: @DomenicoSpidyTamburro if update lib version would help - the best answer is just to update. :)

It's very common situation when parsers can't deal correct with emojies / or when  parsing emojies is broken on some versions.